# How can I plot a solution obtained from Stats.SE?

Tags: plotting, summation

I am trying to implement a solution I got from stats.stackexchange.com in Mathematica, but I must be doing something wrong, because the output I am getting and the accepted answer from stats.stackexchange.com do not agree.:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316296/a-coin-flip-problem/316334#316334

I have tried:

```
n = 20;
p = Sum[Binomial[n - 1, i - 1]/Sum[Binomial[n, i], {i, k, n}], {i, k, n}];
Plot[p, {k, 0, 20}]
```

Comment: Try `ListPlot[  Table[p,{k,0,20}]  ]` instead of `Plot`.

Comment: Define `p[k_] := Sum[Binomial[n - 1, i - 1], {i, k, n}]/
  Sum[Binomial[n, i], {i, k, n}]`, and then `Plot[p[k], {k, 0, 20}]`.

Comment: @aadvark2012 That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html).

With `p` and `n` defined as in OP, then

```
DiscretePlot[p, {k, 0, n}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.